# How to use multithreading in STA aplication vb.net 4.0

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, coded-ui-tests

I am new to threading concept. I want search for UITestControl (MS Coded UI) using Parallel execution. Coded UI solution is a STA.
Is it possible to set this solution to MTA in programmatically?

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => result1 =GetControl(addBtn),
                () => result2=GetControl(reMoveBtn));
```

I have tried with Task, Thread and delegates.
Is there anyother way to execute above two methods parallel?

Exception Details:

> *Result Message:   Test method SampleThreading.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: The
>   Coded UI Test is running in Single Thread Apartment (STA) mode of COM.
>   In this mode, all the playback calls should happen from the TestMethod
>   thread only and UITestControl should not be shared across TestMethods.
>   Result StackTrace:     at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ThreadUtility.ThrowExceptionIfCrossThreadAccess(IRPFPlayback
>   playback, IScreenElement uiElement)*

Comment: Did you try to use `Task.Scheduler.Current` when creating a `Task`?

Comment: Coded UI is all about user interface automation testing (ultimately manipulating a UI) and so I would have thought it slightly naughty to do that from a **non-UI thread**

Comment: Yes Micky but is it not possible ?

Comment: The code is simply illegal, you cannot refer to controls in a threadpool thread.  The kind you get when you use the Parallel class.  Only way to get ahead is to stop writing code like this.  And to stop waiting for test results, perhaps.

Comment: Hi Hans I just want speed up searching mechanism. Is there any other way ?

Comment: I don't think there is way to use CUIT outside the main thread. But you can try using the native technology (MSAA, UIA etc.) in a different thread, get your element, then create a UITestControl from it in your main thread. It might be a bit complicated because in this case you have to write your own search mechanism.

Comment: Hi Kida, I am thinking in similar lines searching UITestControl in main thread and searching another control (UIA native element of UITestControl) in secondary thread then it return AE element then convert to UITestControl to main thread . Is it right way to do ?

Comment: Yeah it should work. I managed to do this with MSAA so I guess it works with UIA too.

Comment: @RajDiscussion _"but is it not possible?"_ - but why bother?  To manipulate a control from a worker thread means that the call must be _thread-marshalled_ to the UI thread via the _Windows Message Pump_ (a rather **costly exercise**) thus negating any performance benefit of using threads if the primary reason of those threads is to interact with a UI.

Comment: @kida MSAA is COM-based and I suspect it was doing the marshalling for you